# How to use BMI function in ARMv8

Tags: arm, armv8

Currently doing a project for school in Arm Assembly and I've run into a strange problem early on. The program takes two integers as input and is supposed to print the first integer and then, print the absolute value of that integer. The problem is that when I input a negative value, I can't find a way to identify that it is negative, as no matter what kind of branch condition I use the branch is not taken.

This is in Armv8, I've tried to compare the value in x1 to #0 and use BLT and BMI both, but it seems that in either case the branch is not taken. Interestingly the value is always printed as negative, so I'm very confused as to how this works.

```
.data

newline: .asciz "\n"
input_fmt: .asciz "%d %d"
output_fmt: .asciz "%d"
strfmt: .asciz "hello"

num1: .space 256
num2: .space 256



.text
.global main

main:

    //take input
    ldr x0, =input_fmt
    ldr x1, =num1
    ldr x2, =num2

    bl scanf

    ldr x0, =output_fmt
    ldr x1, =num1
    ldr x1, [x1]

    bl printf

    ldr x1, =num1
    ldr x1, [x1]
    cmp x1, #0      //<---- PROBLEM
    bmi ABS         //Branch is never taken, even when input is negative

    ldr x0, =output_fmt
    bl printf





    b exit


ABS:

        neg x1, x1
        br x30


exit:
    mov x0, #0
    mov x8, #93
    svc #0
```

Comment: You're loading/storing 64-bit registers in assembly, but the `printf()/scanf()`-conversion specifiers are for 32-bit numbers. `.space` zeroes the memory, so the bytes that `scanf()` doesn't touch are zero. On a little-endian architecture like modern ARM, your inputs *are* always positive when interpreted as 64-bit signed numbers.

Comment: Note that if you fix this bug, you'll hit the next bug immediately afterwards. I recommend learning to use a debugger like `gdb`.